# Вычисление векторного выражения

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм, математика

Даны векторы x,y, состоящие из 6 элементов. A,B,C - матрицы размером 6*6. Напишите программу для вычисления выражения:

(Ax, y)+(By, x)/ (Cx, y)

Может ли кто нибудь подробно объяснить эту задачу?

Comment: Векотор - это неограниченный отрезок, как вы знаете из школьного курса геометрии. Значит, x, y - динамические массивы, в вашем случае.

---
Задача, на самом деле, простая. Тут только надо знать правила, по которым происходит перемножение матриц, множеств и т.д.

Comment: @Asen Колмогоров не одобряет ваше определение вектора :)

Comment: вектор - направленный отрезок. буде он неограниченным, у него бы не было длины

Comment: Нет длины у луча, т.е. собственно направления. Но любой луч (полупрямую) можно задать вектором....

Comment: @renegator, в том-то и дело, что длина у него есть, но непостоянная.

Comment: @Asen

- Имеющее смысл для данной задачи определение `n`-мерного вектора звучит как "*кортеж из `n` элементов некоторого множества*.

- Понятие длины для вектора обычно вводят только для двумерных и трехмерных векторов *на вещественных или целых числах* - тогда каждый элемент вектора считается равным координате по соответствующей оси от нуля и длина приобретает физический смысл. 

- Для `n`-мерного вектора понятие длины либо не имеет смысла, либо всегда принимается равным `n`.

- **Очевидно, что длина вектора - это постоянная величина для каждого отдельно взятого вектора.**

Comment: это почему для n-мерного вектора теряет смысл понятие длины? потому что наш бренный мир трехмерный? вектор - упорядоченная пара точек. длина вектора - расстояние между этими точками. расстояние между точками в n-мерном пространстве имеет вполне определенный смысл и определенную формулу для вычисления - корень квадратный из суммы квадратов разниц координат

Comment: добавлю еще - сущность "вектор" в векторной алгебре и в линейной алгебре не сводимы одна к другой

Answer (score 2):

Вектор в данном случае - это массив из 6 элементов. То есть имеете массивы x, y на 6 чисел. Чтобы вычислить ваше выражение, нужно знать принцип перемножения, деления, сложения матриц. Это смотрите в курсе матанализа.

Comment: Вектор - это строчная матрица или?

Comment: да, это матрица размером 1х6 в данном случае.

Comment: @carapuz Линейной алгебры, скорее уж.

Comment: Да, Вы правы. Ошибся

Comment: Ax и y понятно. А вот что значит (Ax, y)?

Comment: @coderthe Скалярное произведение двух векторов.

Answer (score 2):

x - столбец из 6 элементов

А - матрица 6х6

Ах => произведение матрицы на столбец => это столбец из 6 элементов, где каждый элемент имеет вид:

Сумма(ai1*xi+ai2*xi+ai3*xi+ai4*xi+ai5*xi+ai6*xi),
где i = 1..6 - номер строки.

(Ах,y) - скалярное произведение двух векторов, которое вычисляется следующим образом:

примем z=Ax, тогда (Ax,y)=(z,y)=Сумма(zi*yi), где i=1..6 - номер элемента в векторе.

Ответ скалярного произведения - число.

Для остальных выражений - аналогично. В результате получается: число1+число2/число3 = число.

[Умножение матрицы на вектор](http://ien.izi.vlsu.ru/teach/books/004/les14/lecture.html).

[Скалярное произведение](http://mathematics.ru/courses/stereometry/content/chapter9/section/paragraph5/theory.html).